# Reverse SSH Connection

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

this question is not directly about reverse tunnels or port forwarding, but the answer might be in there..

The situation:
I have a couple of workstations that I want to control using SSH. However, due to the design, I want them to be the clients not the server.

In a regular SSH setup: client connect to the server, client issue commands to the server.

Here, I want the opposite: client connect to the server, client receives command from the server.

The question:
Is that possible to achieve? Or is it written in stone that a client request and a server answer? If yes, can you please show a diagram or maybe name of the technique that can be used to achieve that? I am thinking about creating a channel within the connection but that channel goes from server to client (i.e. client connect to server port 22, within that connection, the server creates a new channel and start executing commands to the client)

I am willing to do some programming using libssh or libssh2, but I am not sure if the SSH protocol allow such thing and hence I decided to ask the networking Guru's (instead of asking in a programming community).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apart from having a server on both ends and merely forwarding the SSH port from the workstation to the server through SSH itself, I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

From client:

> ssh -R 7000:localhost:22 root@server

now you have a reverse tunnel

From server: run commands on client

> ssh root@localhost -p 7000 ls